# Deserialize custom file type byte stream to POCO object in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, deserialization

I need to read in a custom file type into a .Net Core application from a `HttpPost` call.  The current route code is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Path.To.Controllers
{
    public class TransformationController : BaseController
    {
        public TransformationController()
        {
        }


        [Route("transform")]
        [Consumes("application/octet-stream")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Transform()
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                SomeType poco = null;

                try
                {
                    poco = (SomeType)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest(e);
                }


                return Ok(poco);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error from my POST:
`The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 43-54-30-30-31-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-20 ..."`

Post call:

```
POST /transform HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 46848
Authorization: bearer REDACTED
Origin: http://localhost:9001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9001/iframe.html?
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Now, I believe the source of the issue is that the byte stream doesn't contain type information for C# to do the conversion; however I am unsure how to get past that problem.

Questions:
How do I read in a custom file type?  Is there a way to do it without using a stream or do I have to define my own deserializer?  If not, is there an example I can look at to know what I'm getting into?

Comment: Is the application posting to your action serializing data using BinaryFormatter? If you have control over both ends, using a human-readable serializer such as JsonSerializer may make debugging easier.

Comment: This will be coming from a client side service written in React/TS so no.  I do have control over both ends, but the file type is not human readable and making it human readable from the client side would not get past review.

Comment: There are any number of binary formats. You need to know what format the client side used in order to deserialize it. You also need to ensure the other side has the exact same definition of `SomeType` or it will not work (tricky when it comes to versioning). Binary format offers almost zero security vs. human-readable. If something valuable is being passed from client to server, you need to have transport layer security (e.g. https). Hackers easily decypher binary formats.

Comment: That makes sense.  How would I include that information with the request?  The upside is this type is very unlikely to change as it is a legacy format.  As for security, our public environments use https, http is only in use for local testing.

Comment: What about an HTTP header to include the file format type on the request? Anyway `BinaryFormatter` is a .NET specific serialization method, it will work only if the content was serialized using the same .NET framework version and the same object type.

Comment: I guess what I mean to ask in reference to Eric J's comment: How do I determine the method by which the file was serialized so the server side API can deserialize?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures ?

Comment: Doesn't match any of those signatures.  This is an ancient proprietary file type used by only our company internally.  But if it had to be serialized by a C# serializer to be deserialized by one, that leaves me with the "roll my own" solution.

Comment: Tried adding a parameter of type byte[]?

Comment: Take a lot at this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers?Page=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to read in a custom file type

As long as there is no built-in implementation in .NET or no library that implements the specific file type you use, you need to parse the content yourself and interpret each byte / part of the binary stream yourself based on the definition of this custom file type.

`BinaryFormatter` uses its own format, so you can only deserialise content with it that was generated by another `BinaryFormatter`. Also, binary serialisation in .NET is not guaranteed to work across different framework implementations. So binary content generated by .NET Framework may not necessarily be usable on .NET Core or Mono.